# Insert scripts in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I want to insert a script to a Drupal page. What I can find there's no footer.tpl.php or head.tpl.php. I can find the page.tpl.php and tried to insert the script there but with no luck. I just want to add the script to a specific page therefore I tried to hard code it into the body of that page but with no luck. Where do I insert a script tag, there's to themes installed as far as I know and it's Base and Garland.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of adding javascript to a page is using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7). By default, if you specify a file to add, it will add it in the  section of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

reallyxloco is correct about using drupal_add_js to add your script. What you'd need to do is add that into your template.php file.

The tpl file that you are probably trying to locate is likely html.tpl.php but depending on your version of Drupal, that might be a core file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use drupal_add_js and it works. The thing is for the script to work it has to be inserted in the footer which also works, but drupal adds a slash in front of the src like this "/http://www.example.js", trying to say that the script is a external script but without no success, here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
  drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'module','footer',FALSE,FALSE,FALSE);
?>
```